# Split String by Regex Expression

Tags: c#, regex, string

This is my string.

```
19282511~2017-08-28 13:24:28~Entering (A/B)~1013~283264/89282511~2017-08-28 13:24:28~Entering (A/B)~1013~283266/79282511~2017-08-28 13:24:28~Entering (A/B)~1013~283261
```

I would like this string be split like below:

```
19282511~2017-08-28 13:24:28~Entering (A/B)~1013~283264
89282511~2017-08-28 13:24:28~Entering (A/B)~1013~283266
79282511~2017-08-28 13:24:28~Entering (A/B)~1013~283261
```

I cannot split my string blindly by slash (/) since there is a value `A/B` will also get split.

Any idea of doing this by regex expression?

Your help will definitely be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may split with `/` that is in between digits:

```
(?<=\d)/(?=\d)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5Cd%29%2F%28%3F%3D%5Cd%29&i=19282511%7E2017-08-28%2013%3A24%3A28%7EEntering%20%28A%2FB%29%7E1013%7E283264%2F89282511%7E2017-08-28%2013%3A24%3A28%7EEntering%20%28A%2FB%29%7E1013%7E283266%2F79282511%7E2017-08-28%2013%3A24%3A28%7EEntering%20%28A%2FB%29%7E1013%7E283261)

**Details**

- `(?<=\d)` - a positive lookbehind that requires a digit to appear immediately to the left of the current location
- `/` - a `/` char
- `(?=\d)` - a positive lookahead that requires a digit to appear immediately to the right of the current location.

Since the `\d` pattern is inside non-consuming patterns, only `/` will be removed upon splitting and the digits will remain in the resulting items.

[image]

Another idea is to match and *capture* these strings using

```
/?([^~]*(?:~[^~]*){3}~\d+)
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2F%3F%28%5B%5E%7E%5D*%28%3F%3A%7E%5B%5E%7E%5D*%29%7B3%7D%7E%5Cd%2B%29&i=19282511%7E2017-08-28%2013%3A24%3A28%7EEntering%20%28A%2FB%29%7E1013%7E283264%2F89282511%7E2017-08-28%2013%3A24%3A28%7EEntering%20%28A%2FB%29%7E1013%7E283266%2F79282511%7E2017-08-28%2013%3A24%3A28%7EEntering%20%28A%2FB%29%7E1013%7E283261).

**Details**

- `/?` - 1 or 0 `/` chars
- `([^~]*(?:~[^~]*){3}~\d+)` - Group 1 (what you need to grab):

  - `[^~]*` - zero or more chars other than `~`
  - `(?:~[^~]*){3}` - 3 or more sequences of `~` and then 0+ chars other than `~`
  - `~\d+` - a `~` and then 1 or more digits.
    The C# code will look like

  var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"/?([^~]*(?:~[^~]*){3}~\d+)")
          .Cast()
          .Select(m => m.Groups[1](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5Cd%29%2F%28%3F%3D%5Cd%29&i=19282511%7E2017-08-28%2013%3A24%3A28%7EEntering%20%28A%2FB%29%7E1013%7E283264%2F89282511%7E2017-08-28%2013%3A24%3A28%7EEntering%20%28A%2FB%29%7E1013%7E283266%2F79282511%7E2017-08-28%2013%3A24%3A28%7EEntering%20%28A%2FB%29%7E1013%7E283261).Value)
          .ToList();

[image]

**NOTE**: By default, `\d` matches all Unicode digits. If you do not want this behavior, use the `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option, or replace `\d` with `[0-9]` to only match ASCII digits.

Comment: This is beauty of Regex. Thanks much for the quick and wonderful answer. I will accept this as an answer in 7 minutes.